# how to add column names to row values based on certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Cricket':[0, 0, 1, 0],
       'Football':[1, 0, 1, 0],
       'Hockey':[1, 0, 1, 0],
       'Soccer':[1, 1, 1, 0],
       'Kabadi':[0, 0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

It looks as follows:

```
    Name    Cricket Football    Hockey  Soccer  Kabadi
0   Tom     0       1           1       1       0
1   nick    0       0           0       1       0
2   krish   1       1           1       1       1
3   jack    0       0           0       0       0
```

I want create a new dataframe based on the values that equals to 1 such that the dataframe looks as follows:

```
Name   Games
Tom    Football,Hockey,Soccer
nick   Soccer
krish  Cricket,Football,Hockey,Soccer,Kabadi
jack
```

Any help appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by all columns names without first:

```
df = df.set_index('Name').dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str[:-1].reset_index(name='Games')
print (df)
    Name                                  Games
0    Tom                 Football,Hockey,Soccer
1   nick                                 Soccer
2  krish  Cricket,Football,Hockey,Soccer,Kabadi
3   jack
```

Comment: sorry sir It will not producing expected output so pls don't test it

Comment: @AnuragDabas it is working perfectly for me. Can you tell us the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @user288925 this work perfectly I suggested jezrael sir a method but later I found that that method doesn't producing expected output....so I was taking about that method(Which was suggested by me)